# validated_data is empty : django

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am trying to get validated_data in serializer , but only gets partial data,

```
views

class CourseList(APIView, ResponseViewMixin):
       def put(self, request, id):
        data = request.data
        instance = self.get_object(id)
        serializer = CourseListSerializer(data=request.data, instance=instance)

        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer = serializer.save()

serializer
       def update(self, instance, validated_data):
            print('instance', instance)
            print('validated_data', validated_data)

input
   {
     "name": "course_1008.1",
     "description": "Description about course_1008.1 ",
     "is_free": "False",
     "section":["ee41b01c-7d8b-4718-84ec-6be497114395"],
     "keyarea":  "2f59abff-2e39-4cc8-aa72-96974ed85ce5"
   }
```

Here when I print validated_data i can see only those items ::
validated_data {'name': 'course', 'description': 'Description ', 'is_free': False}
How to get the remaining values?

Comment: can you post your serializer here? basically you will get only those fields in validated_data which you have specified in serializer. if you want to get other items you can use instance.

Comment: you can get it by validated_data.get('name') in serializer function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are trying to update without returning anything.

```
class CourseListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CourseList
        fields = '__all__'

    def update(self, instance, validate_data):
        print('INSTANCE -->', instance)
        print('VALIDATE -->', validate_data)
        # only to see the result...
        return instance # < ---------
```

Result:

```
INSTANCE --> 23  # <----- example of an/your object id
VALIDATE --> {"name": "course_1008.1", 
"description": "Description about course_1008.1 ","is_free": "False"....all the rest....}
```

First you are not showing us how is you serializer (I am guessing here). Second you are not returning a value in your update() method. Also, check if you are proper sending data everynow and again we may face it.